# Java/Android: Increment Algorithm

Tags: java, android

I have a value of Android accelerometer x axis, and on every **0.18** change of that value, the value of **az** should also be incrementally/decrementally changed by **5**

for example:

at `x=0,    az=0`

at `x=0.18, az=5`

at `x=0.36, az=10`

if the value of x back to 0.18, so az value must also be back to 5 (that means x and az are synchronized)

How should I implement this logic into codes?

PS: I expect "for", "if", or maybe "while" statements here

Sorry for my bad English. Thank you in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I presume you have some way of continually monitoring the `x` value. In which case, pseudo-code:

```
private static final double xToAz = 5.0/0.18;    

onChange(x)
{        
    az = xToAz * x;
    az -= az%5;
}
```

Comment: This isn't granular. It simply performs the math blindly, without implementing the notches OP asked for.

Comment: Ah, I hadn't considered that he wanted discrete changes. Edited.

Comment: Much better. Nice and short, too! :)

Answer (score 0):

Devide x with 0.18 and multiply the result with 5 to get the value of az.

```
az = (x / 0.18) * 5;
```

Comment: This won't provide the granularity that OP is asking for. It'll result in 8.3333 rather than 5 for an input of 0.3, for example.